# Xpath not behaving for me in parsing basic html

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to parse some basic html using xpath and running into issues. The returned output is always empty using what I am reading the xpath docs to say works. Below is my first attempt at making this work. Any help is appreciated as always guys and gals.

```
$html  = '<ul>';
$html .= '  <li id="stuff-12345"> some content here </li>';
$html .= '  <li id="stuff-54321"> some other content here </li>';
$html .= '</ul>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument(); 
    $dom->loadHTML($html);  
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
    $result = $xpath->query('//ul/li'); 
    foreach($result as $e){
        echo $e->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: This is more of an PHP question than an XPath one. Your XPath expression is correct.

Comment: thanks dimitri, lets hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong now  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMXPath::query` returns a `DOMNodeList`. When you are doing

```
foreach($result as $e){
```

you are iterating over the `DOMElement` items a `DOMNodeList`. `DOMElement` does not have an `item()` method. Only `DOMNodeList` has that. Try with

```
foreach($result as $e){
    echo $e->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked perfectly. Do you happen to know how I could refine the xpath query to only get li's with id="stuff-###" ? I could not seem to find anything in the docs where a wildcard could be used.

Comment: @Jaime `//ul/li[@id="stuff-12345"]` to get that exact ID. `//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "stuff")]` to get li elements having an id attribute value starting with 'stuff' and `'//ul/li[contains(@id, "stuff")]'` to get li elements having 'stuff' anywhere in the id attribute