# return multiple nodes with xpath

Tags: php, parsing

how do i return more than one node on a page? here is the code i am using, but it only returns the 1st node found.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($URL);

$xpath  = new DOMXpath($dom);
$users= $xpath->query('//b[@class="xc_user"]');

echo $users->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Use `foreach` to iterate the returned [`DOMNodeList`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) or [any other loop control structure.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Comment: @Gordon I tried this `foreach ($users->item->nodeValue as $result) { echo $result; }` no luck is this in the right direction?

Comment: Just `foreach ($user as $node)`. This will return a `DOMElement` for `$node`. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249492/xpath-not-behaving-for-me-in-parsing-basic-html/5249675#5249675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$users` is a DOMNodeList, which you can iterate over:

```
foreach($users as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```